# How to find a string in field and add an url before it in mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I would like to know how to find in a table field all possible instances of a string e.g.

```
uploads/
```

and add before all of them another string e.g.

```
http://example.com/
```

My idea is to update all my records in database where the old links are not working so for instace I have something like this for a field **perex**

```
Check this car <img src="/uploads/audi.jpg">. It is fantastic!
```

To look like:

```
Check this car <img src="http://example.com/uploads/audi.jpg">. It is fantastic!
```

And I have hundreds of this situations in my db.

What could an update query look like? Assume we have it in one table called **cars** and field is called **perex**. We need to find there all instances of **/uploads** and add before the slash **http://example.com/**

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE cars
SET perex = REPLACE(perex, '/uploads/', 'http://example.com/uploads/')
WHERE INSTR(perex, '/uploads/');
```

See:

- [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)
- [`INSTR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Update table
set Perex = Replace (Perex, 'Check this car <img src="', 'Check this car <img src="http://example.com')
Where Perex like '%uploads/%'
```